# Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range…' INSERT INTO MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, sql-insert

I know there is lot of question of the same type but no one helped me and I'am really stuck. 
So I'am trying to send Data from an Excel table with VBA and I always get the same error : 'Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range' 
The thing is i can't understand where my mistake comes from ? Is it from my SQL query or from the visual basic code ? 
My code is in 3 sub

```vb
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
```

the second one

```vb
Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim str As String

    str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
          "SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" & ";" & _
          "PORT=3306" & ";" & _
          "DATABASE=myDB" & ";" & _
          "USER=User" & ";" & _
          "PASSWORD=pwd" & ";" & _
          "Option=3"

    ''' error '''
    oConn.Open str
End Sub
```

And the last one

```vb
Sub InsertData()    
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Requete As String

    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Call ConnectDB
    With Sheets("Feuil5")
        Requete = "INSERT INTO Position (Emplacement,Etage,Colonne,Taille) VALUES ('1','1','1','1');"
        Rs.Open Requete, oConnect, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    End With
    Debug.Print Requete
    oConnect.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Could someone find my mistake and help realisyzing and simple sql query in vba ?

Comment: You're inserting strings into the `Position` table. Are the columns string values?

Comment: Wait why do you have `oConn` declared in another scope? `Dim` is for local variables, so `ConnectDB` is assigning to an undeclared variabel. Have `Option Explicit` specified at the top of every module, then declare your local variables until for code compiles again (Debug ~> Compile VBAProject). What is the error on `oConn.Open str` (note, `Str` is a terrible name that actually hides an existing globally-scoped function from the VBA standard library).

Comment: The insert is probably failing because you're inserting 5 values into 4 columns.

Comment: So yes all my columns are of Varchar datatype which is a variable String right ?.
I've mooved `Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection` after `Private Sub ConnectDB()`.
I've tried to had Option Explicit but i get an error everytime.
I don't have any error on `oConn.Open str` and i changed str for S now

Comment: You're getting errors with `Option Explicit` because you're using variables that aren't declared anywhere, or are otherwise inaccessible: that is exactly as intended - `Option Explicit` helps enforce correctness, by refusing to compile code that uses undeclared variables. The solution is to declare your variables, not to remove `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Okey I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The job of `ConnectDB` is to create a database connection. Instead of assigning to some `oConn` object (which may already be connected and opened) declared in another scope, make it a `Function`.

```vb
Private Function ConnectDB() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    Const connString As String = _
      "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
      "SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;" & _
      "PORT=3306l" & _
      "DATABASE=myDB;" & _
      "USER=User;" & _
      "PASSWORD=pwd;" & _
      "Option=3"

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    conn.Open connString
    Set ConnectDB = conn
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Error opening database connection:"
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Debug.Print "ConnectDB is returning Nothing."
    Set ConnectDB = Nothing
End Function
```

Now you have a function that either connects and returns a live `ADODB.Connection`, or doesn't and returns `Nothing` instead - and all values involved aren't scoped any wider than they need to be.

So `InsertData` can now use it. Now, we don't need a `Recordset` at all - we don't care about any records, we just want to run an `INSERT` query; this can run against the connection itself - note that the number of `VALUES` must match the number of columns specified in the `INSERT INTO` clause... and since a hard-coded set of values isn't very useful, you'll want these values properly parameterized (DO NOT concatenate worksheet cell values into your SQL statement - [meet *Little Bobby Tables*](https://xkcd.com/327/)):

```vb
Public Sub InsertData(ByVal emplacement As String, ByVal etage As String, ByVal colonne As String, ByVal taille As String)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = ConnectDB
    If conn Is Nothing Then
        ' couldn't connect to database; review Debug output, fix connection string.
        MsgBox "Could not connect to database.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Const sql As String = _
        "INSERT INTO Position (Emplacement, Etage, Colonne, Taille) " &
        "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) "

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    'TODO: verify parameter types & sizes.
    'NOTE: parameters must be added in the order they are specified in the SQL.
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=emplacement)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=etage)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=colonne)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=200, Value:=taille)

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    cmd.Execute '<~ when you DO need a recordset, this gets you your recordset.
CleanExit:
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Error executing command: " & sql
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm really sry but I'm beginning with vba and I don't understand where I'm supposed to add a `Cell(1,2)` for example. Should I add this after `Value:=` instead of emplacement ?

Comment: @LukaAUDE the procedure takes 4 parameters; when you invoke that procedure, you supply the values - they could come from a worksheet cell, hard-coded test input, or anything.. the procedure doesn't need to know. `InsertData Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value, Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value, Sheet1.Vells(1, 4).Value, Sheet1.Cells(1, 5).Value` is just as valid as `InsertData "test", "test", "test", "test"`

Answer (score 0):

Okey so to solve this problem I added all in one sub and here what I have know :

```vb
Private Sub ConnectDB()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Requete As String
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim S As String

S = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
      "SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" & ";" & _
      "PORT=3306" & ";" & _
      "DATABASE=x" & ";" & _
      "USER=x" & ";" & _
      "PASSWORD=x" & ";" & _
      "Option=3"

''' error '''
oConn.Open S

Requete = "INSERT INTO Position(Emplacement,Etage,Colonne,Taille) VALUES('test','test','test','test');"

    Rs.Open Requete, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    Debug.Print Requete
    oConn.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

It solved my initial problem but now I get another problem ( Execution error'-2147217887 (80040e21)':
This driver does not support the requested properties ) but anyway thanks for your help I'am going to try to find my other mistake now. 
Have a nice day